# What is the max length for an input option to RunDeck?

Tags: rundeck

What is the max length of an input option for RunDeck?
I am passing in a comma separated list of values.  Passing 25 values (about 150 characters) seems okay but 200 values (about 1400 characters) seems too much.  I can't easily test it because it's a production environment.

I checked the HTML and it has size=40 for the input text field but there seems to be no limit to the content length.
I searched the source code briefly, but I don't know it well enough so I could not find anything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's defined on the [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsHtk.jpg) (H2 or anything else) as varchar 255. Maybe a good idea is to use multiple options.